# Program terminating before if statement

Tags: java

I'm having trouble initializing an if statement in this program. The program terminates before running the if statement every time.  Can anyone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class attempt1 {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        boolean done=false;
        System.out.println("say something");
        userInput=console.nextLine();

        if (userInput.equals("stop")) {
            done=true;
        }
        while(done=false) {
            System.out.println("it worked!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's terminated and it's not waiting for input?

Comment: it should be `while(done==false)`, not `while(done=false)`

Comment: @sashkello quite the opposite; it would never *enter* the loop.

Comment: @BrianRoach Aha, you are right, I forgot how it works in java a bit. The assigned value will be the expression value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this construct

```
    if (userInput.equals("stop")) {
        done=true;
    }
    while(done=false) {
        System.out.println("it worked!");
    }
```

I suppose you wanted to say:

```
    done = userInput.equals("stop")
    if (!done) {
        System.out.println("it worked!");
    }
```

I'm not sure what was the purpose of `while` but you certainly didn't want to use a loop in this case.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want something like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    boolean done=false;

    while(done==false) {
        System.out.println("say something");
        userInput=console.nextLine();
        if (userInput.equals("stop")) {
        done=true;
    }

    }
     System.out.println("it worked!");
}
```

This code asks the user to keep saying something until they say stop at which point it prints out "it worked!"

The program will wait for your input every time you call `userInput=console.nextLine();` It's not terminating, but just waiting for input.

Also, you want == in your while comparison. == compares values while = assigns

Comment: `while(done==false)` can be rewritten as `while(!done)` :)

Comment: that's true, although I think doing the comparison makes more sense for a beginner

Comment: @connor No, it leads the *exactly the problem you're pointing out*; mistyping one instead of two `=` and introducing a bug.

Comment: that's a good point too. I'm leaving it the way it is now because that's the closest to what the author wrote and it's a way to show the difference

Answer (score 1):

Use `do-while` here, it would be easier:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput;
do {
    System.out.println("say something");
    userInput=console.nextLine();
    if(userInput.equals("stop"))
        break;
} while(console.hasNextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a scanner. If the user doesn't enter any data, the program won't run. Try running it with a preset string or int or whatever you need. The code looks fine

Comment: *"The code looks fine"* ... So I assume you missed *"while(done=false)"* then..

Comment: @MadProgrammer i didn't miss that. He has an if statement that would change the boolean value to true. I would assume that when testing a program he would test all possibilities. He is claiming that the program isn't even getting to the if statement. Therefore I assumed that the user didn't give any input

Comment: `done=false` is a reassignment of the `done` value, meaning that it can never be `true` when the `while-loop` is evaluated...this is not "fine" in anybodies book...

Comment: @ChriskOlson `done=false` evaluates to `false` and therefore the loop would never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems here.

Are you certain that there is a next line? To be sure:

```
System.out.println(console.hasNextLine())
```

Also, your boolean is incorrect. Remember that a single '=' is an assignment, and '==' means "is equal to".

Answer (score -1):

You have an infinite loop.

```
while(done=false) {
System.out.println("it worked!");
}
```

This crashes the program. Just simply change while(done=false) to "else if (!done)".

Comment: It wouldn't "crash" anything, and it certainly isn't infinite ... it would evaluate to `false` and never enter the loop.